# java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context

Tags: hibernate, spring

I'm using maven_spring 3.1.M2 + hibernate 3.5. Once I put the line `<tx:annotation-driven />` in my applicationcontex xml file, the follwoing error will occur:

```
WARNING: Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Jul 16 13:00:52 IST 2011]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:350)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1033)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:988)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:534)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4721)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$4.call(StandardContext.java:5423)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$4.call(StandardContext.java:5402)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Please: a) what does your context look like? b) how is your context started (programatically, webapp, etc.) ?

Comment: You might be missing a class, like I was here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8330414/ . Are there any other exceptions?

Answer (score 5):

Do you have AspectJ in your pom.xml or in your lib-directory?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I had the same error and this solved my problem.

Comment: Not work, even already have:
spring-aspects-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar
aspectjrt-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar
aspectjweaver-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar

Comment: I would like to see your `pom.xml` (dependencies only), because I believe that there is a failure in the dependency tree (multiple or not a "fitting" AspectJ and Spring combination).

Comment: Now I have removed everything and restart doing the pom again, and it's no more that error.

I got many projects dependencies that might be the caused but don't know how to specify telling them...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, And solution is the Spring jars
Now it depends on person to person which spring jar his project is using and actually which one is missing.
For me it happened 3-4 times when I created project. Sometime I had all Spring jar but not the Spring.jar
Next time Spring Aspect jar was missing. while some other time I had make sure of all but missed security. But I always fixed it by carefully placing the Spring jars.
No need to look for any other reason.

Hope that help and focus on only Spring jars and not others. Happy Coding guys!!

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue when using both `jersey-spring3` and `spring-core`.
The jersey-spring3.jar, uses its own version for Spring libraries, so to use the ones you want, you need to exclude these libraries manually.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>bean-validator</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

resolve conflict version the spring dependencies in `pom.xml` , may be in various version change class name or add feature that in other dependencies has incompatibility.