# java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm getting the following error when trying to run a project with spring and spring-security (it was running before I added spring security):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Nov 30 10:49:27 CST 2011]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:337)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:324)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1025)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:988)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4778)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4675)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Does anyone know why?  I haven't found anything on the interverse.. here's my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">
    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" />
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
            <user-service>
                <user name="rod" password="a564de63c2d0da68cf47586ee05984d7" authorities="ROLE_SUPERVISOR, ROLE_USER, ROLE_TELLER" />
                <user name="dianne" password="65d15fe9156f9c4bbffd98085992a44e" authorities="ROLE_USER,ROLE_TELLER" />
                <user name="scott" password="2b58af6dddbd072ed27ffc86725d7d3a" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                <user name="peter" password="22b5c9accc6e1ba628cedc63a72d57f8" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

You'll notice it's similar to [the tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html).  I've heard this issue might be a bug?  Also as far as I know I've added the necessary jars and configuration.. but that might be an issue too.  Finally I'm using `spring-beans-3.1.xsd` and `spring-security-3.0.xsd` because those match the major/minor version of the jars I have.

Comment: Have you enabled full DEBUG logging on org.springframework? That should tell you exactly who is trying to broadcast what event. What other spring configuration files are you pulling in? What versions of Spring Framework and Security are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure how to enable that logging on spring.  I'm using spring 3.1.0RC1 and spring-security 3.0.7

Comment: It turned out to be a jar issue, added the relevant jars and things work now :)

Comment: FWIW, I don't think this is too localized.

Comment: @AndrewBarber could you justify your reasons for closing this question or open it again please.  It has 9 upvotes, 0 downvotes, 3 favorites and an intense irritation on an bad answer.  It's also the top Google result for this error message: http://bit.ly/1ik4wzU

Comment: @olafure Just check out the answer from the person who asked the question. "Too Localized" was the closest close reason *a year ago* when I closed this question. I'm going to update it to a more appropriate close reason from what we have now...

Answer (score -42, accepted):

I was missing some spring security jars.  Just didn't think of that when I saw `IllegalStateException`

Comment: What are the missing jar? Can you share all of them? I got the same error but can't figure it out what are the missing...

Comment: Any answers on what those JARs are?

Comment: what were missing jars ?

Comment: Would be great if you could post the missing jars.

Comment: The purpose of posting a question is to get help from others and also to help others, not for us to know that you have fixed your problem!!!

Comment: @Josh - Where we need to put the Spring-Security file ? Any suggestion please...

Comment: @Josh You should give detail explanation of solution so that other can get help from that

Comment: Which jar was that.. First time iam seeing downvotes for an answer.. :D

Comment: please post the jars

Comment: Facing the same proble, **please** list the jars/dependencies

Comment: And how does those missing jars help ? share the missing jars, please.

Comment: Well, it seems many people are having this issue and still no answer. I also had this problem (with Spring Boot). I have managed to fix it by adding the spring-aspects dependency.

Comment: @Josh: what libs were missing?

Comment: 404 jar not found - 6 years and counting

Comment: I added all the dependencies from here and it worked: https://www.jumpingbean.co.za/hibernate-4.0.1-pom.xml

Answer (score 10):

add to your ***pom.xml***. This will solve the problem

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This resolved my problem ... thanks.

Comment: thank u it resolved my problem.

Comment: Can you explain why this will solve the problem ?

Comment: In my case, that doesn't work.

Comment: This does not solve the problem