# Spring Application Not Starting Properly - Doesnot show error either

Tags: java, spring

I am new to Spring Boot framework. I have created Spring Boot application and it runs fine on one machine. I ported the jar file to another machine with same version of java i.e. 1.8. It worked for the first time and now it does not start up correctly. Following is the debug output:

```
java -Ddebug -Dserver.port=8089 -jar pentaho_webservices.jar
```

[image: Spring Output]

It does nothing and gets stuck there. How can I debug what's going wrong, if I am running it in another machine, it shows additional steps as follows:

[image: Spring Output - II]

If I cancel the job, it gives following error:

```
2015-09-18 03:11:19.219  WARN 3125 --- [       Thread-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close

java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2df32bf7: startup date [Fri Sep 18 02:58:23 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:357)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.doClose(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:150)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:804)
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated!

**Stack trace screenshots :**

[image]
[image]
Regards, 
Pratikshya

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716087/java-lang-illegalstateexception-lifecycleprocessor-not-initialized-call-refr

Comment: Did you try adding the spring aspect jars as dependency?

Comment: Yes, I added aspect jar dependencies as well. It still does not work. It does not even throw any error. Just it gets stuck to that point and does nothing.